# why jquery detach element will cause a form to submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wonder why in the following example, trying to `detach` an element (`li`) causes the `form` containing it to `submit`

**html**

```
<form id="frmToDo" name="frmToDo">
  <p id="lineInput">
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Add" />
  </p>
  <ul id="todolist">
      <!-- added in ajax -->
  </ul>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$("#frmToDo").submit(function() {
    // this runs after: $("#todolist").detach(...)
});

$("#todolist").delegate("li[id^=task-] button", "click", function() {
    $("#todolist").detach($($(this).parent()).id());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What is `.id()`? No such thing in jQuery that I'm aware of.

Comment: it seems like replacing `.id()` with `attr("id")` fixes the problem of the form submit, delegate didn't work still. but wondering why will this mistake cause the form to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just want to remove the `li` element in which the button was clicked.

So instead of using

```
$("#todolist").delegate("li[id^=task-] button", "click", function() {
    $("#todolist").detach($($(this).parent()).id());
    return false;
});
```

Try using

```
$("#todolist").delegate("li[id^=task-] button", "click", function() {
    $(this).parent().detach();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a button, it's an input element.

```
$("#todolist").delegate("li[id^=task-] input:submit", "click", function() {
```

Comment: The one shown is not inside the list. However, it is possible that the OP has confused the two.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem but you are not using the `detach` function correctly if your intention is to detach an `li` element. The argument of the `detach` function is a selector expression that filters the set of matched element in the jQuery element that you are calling the function on. In your code you call `detach` on `$('#todolist')`, which means you want to detach the todolist element, if it matches the argument passed.

You should do something like this instead :

```
$('#todolist li').detach(); //this will detach all the li elements
```

I am not sure if this can explain the fact that your form is submitting. If it is not : what event triggers the submit event of your form ? Maybe you use a button or input element that is placed inside the form and triggers the submit of the form ?

Comment: a `<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Add" />` does

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some relevant code missing, you seem to assign a handler to the `onclick` event outside a `$(document).ready()` block. That makes it possible to run the assignment before the `#todolist` is loaded, thus failing to find the buttons and attach handlers.

With no event cancelling, the default behaviur for a button is to submit the form.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frmToDo").submit(function() {
        // this runs after: $("#todolist").detach(...)
    });

    $("#todolist").delegate("li[id^=task-] button", "click", function() {
        $("#todolist").detach($($(this).parent()).id());
        return false;
    });
});
```